# Angular 4 - Post Checkboxes from an array

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

I am trying to print checkboxes from an array with a checkbox, to later

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>class</th>
            <th>subjects</th>
            <th>class speaker</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let class of classes">
            <td>{{ class.name }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="form">
                    <input type="text" class="md-input-text" placeholder=" " value=" " [(ngModel)]="subject" />
                    <label class="md-desc">subjects</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="md-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ class.id }}" [(ngModel)]="checkBoxValue" />
                    <label for="{{ class.id }}"></label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, if I check one of the checkboxes, every one of those will be checked too. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should provide a `name` for Input types. If there are more than one `input` with same name, you can get the checked value from it.

Comment: Does `[(ngModel)]="class['checkBoxValue']"` work? I haven't spent much time on 2+, but I think that's about the right syntax to have a checkBoxValue on each class object. Thus classes[0].checkBoxValue would get you the value your first object...

Comment: [(ngModel)]="class['checkBoxValue']" works like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: @Brian it would be good if you posted that as an answer for future users. You said you weren't familiar with Angular 2 so here is the documentation [link for template forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `[(ngModel)]="checkBoxValue"` to `[(ngModel)]="class['checkBoxValue']"`. Thus classes[0].checkBoxValue would get you the value your first object, and so on. The way it is currently configured, they (the checkboxes) are all bound to the same value on scope, and thus all respond to change synchronously.

Comment: Seems like I was wrong. My checkbox array print is like this `this is my checkBoxValue: true,false,false` but when I try to use this `<input type="checkbox" id="{{ class.id }}"  [(ngModel)]="class['checkBoxValue']"/>
` the first one isnt checked